# Getting Unknown arguments error while creating a charge in stripe in node

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Getting Unknown arguments error while creating a charge in stripe with node

nhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Stripe: Unknown arguments ([object Object]). Did you mean to pass an options object? See https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/wiki/Passing-Options. (on API request to POST `/charges`)

The code which i used for the payment

```
const {v4:uuid4} =require('uuid');

const stripe = require("stripe")(SECRET_KEY);


module.exports = (app) => {

    app.post("/payment",(req,res)=>{
    
      const {product, token} = req.body;
  
      console.log("PRICE", product.price);
      console.log("PRICE", token.email);
      const idempontencyKey = uuid4()

  try {
      return stripe.customers.create({
        email: token.email,
        source:token.id
      }).then(customer => {
        stripe.charges.create(
        {
          amount: product.price * 100,
          currency: 'usd',
          customer: customer.id,
          receipt_email: token.email,
        }, 
        {
          idempontencyKey
        });

      })
      .then(result => res.status(200).json(result))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))

  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }



    });
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you misspelled `idempotencyKey`, and you need to return `stripe.charges.create()` but otherwise I'm not sure what might be going wrong here based on the code you've provided - what happens if you remove the object with idempotencyKey?  Does it work?

Comment: Hi correcting the spelling of "idempotencyKey" worked....thanks for the help.

Comment: Awesome - you're welcome! :)